# Active directory login and check role in custom SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

I would to create a code that user need to login using Active Directory. 
After login successful, back end code will query the user role in SQL Database.
Before i create the code below Active Directory is totally work

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
var role1 = "";
if (role1 == "1") 
{
    string selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM [UniKL].[dbo].[BudgetPlanning_User]";
    Response.Redirect("~/home.aspx");
} 
else {
    Response.Redirect("~/logout.aspx");
}
   }
```

After I insert the code above active directory and sql query is not work. It will redirect to logout.aspx page.

Answer (score 1):

You can create roles in Active Directory as well (known as Groups in AD)
Steps you should take care of:

1. Create Active directory login
2. Create Groups (as per your roles) and add users in groups. For e.g., 'AdminRole' group can have user 'AdminUser', 'ModeratorRole' can have 'ModUser' and so on..
3. Validate these groups as well on user login module. (I can give code to you for that)
4. Perform your operations based on those roles.

But to answer your question specifically, If you want roles to be stored in SQL DB, You need to have tables with `User.Identity.Name` stored with `RoleId` along with them.

After logic, query to database with `User.Identity.Name` as parameter and get user's role.

Let me know if i can help you more with this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to use role that are stored in SQL DB. I already create table with name BudgetPlanning_user and the field ni Role. If equal to 1 user can access and 0 user cannot be access.